# Looking for advice on updating an online database with SMS

Tags: php, mysql, database, sms

I am looking to write a small application that receives an SMS text message and records the results in an online database. I am most comfortable with php/mysql, but can use any suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote something cute and small like this last summer, but I cheated using an actual SMS server and used Twitter to receive my text messages in a specific format, then had a daemon service running through my RSS feed every *n* time units to pull in the data and store it in a flat file. It was a fun exercise, and free, and as far as I know no free SMS receivers are available. You can use MySQL if you want, but I feel like you'll need a language that's more designed for writing a service than a web application (i.e. PHP)

Comment: interesting, creative approach to the SMS thing.  it surprises me how difficult it is to hook into the whole SMS system

Comment: Nice, it is simple. i like it.

Comment: I do something similar (well!! not exaclty) for my ubuntu server http://www.crankup.net/i-am-tweeting-with-luv-my-ubuntu-server

Answer (score 0):

I've used [clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/developers.php) for setting up SMS notification for Nagios.  Never used them to receive text message though.  My guess is you probably give them some magic URL and they hit it up with with a POST containing all the data in the message.

You'll ever find anything that is free though.  In fact, you might find that SMS is rather expensive if you do a lot of volume.  Even $0.01/message is a lot when you are sending 10k messages a week.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to setup your own server, then you can make use of [gnokii](http://www.gnokii.org). You will have to physically connect a Nokia mobile phone and once you receive the messages, you can add them to a database.